# How can my macro prompt for a single cell selection without needing to click okay on an inputbox?

Tags: excel, vba, select, cell, prompt

I have an Excel macro that copies several cells from part of the worksheet to another. The macro uses inputbox to prompt the user to select a date to copy from and then prompts to select a date to paste to. The macro then copies several cells near the "from" date and pastes the information to the corresponding cells near the "to" date. Everything works, but it is a drag having to click okay on the inputbox after every selection. Is there a way to streamline this so the user only has to click the "from" and "to" cells?

Current process:

1. Click macro call button.
2. Click "from" cell.
3. Click okay on inputbox.
4. Click "to" cell.
5. click okay on inputbox.

Desired process:

1. Click macro call button.
2. Click "from" cell.
3. Click "to" cell.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim fromdate As Range
Dim todate As Range
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
For x = 1 To 3
Set fromdate = Application.InputBox("Select copy from date", "Select copy from date", Type:=8)
If IsDate(fromdate.Value) = True Then 'ensure selected cell is a date
   For y = 1 To 3
   Set todate = Application.InputBox("Select copy to date", "Select copy to date", Type:=8)
   If IsDate(todate.Value) Then 'ensure selected cell is a date
     ActiveSheet.Protect
     'copy data
     todate.Offset(1, 1) = fromdate.Offset(1, 1)
     todate.Offset(1, 4) = fromdate.Offset(1, 4)
     End
   End If
   MsgBox "Pick the date cell"
   Next y
End If
MsgBox "Pick the date cell"
Next x
ActiveSheet.Protect
```

As I stated above, this code works fine. I just don't want to have to click okay on the input box that pops up. I am hoping that there is some other command I can use instead of inputbox. I want to copy the data with three clicks. One to run the macro, one to select the "from" date, and one to select the "to date.

Comment: That's not a question. Please look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then also take a look at [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then edit your question and get some answers.

Comment: I looked over your links (again) and I am not sure what you are looking for. Can you be more specific? The title is a question. The description provides more information and clarifies the question.

Comment: @Mailbox The issue is, there is no code in your question. So we cannot help you with your code if we don't see it. You need to show what you have done/tried so far, then explain what errors you got and where, or what your code actually did and what you expect it to do. If your code is not short then create a [mcve] that represents the issue you have.

Comment: I have updated my post with the code I am using. It works just like it should with no problems or errors. I am just looking for a way to reduce my "click count" when running the code. thanks for your consideration and help.